# Get Generic Inquiry to display in user's setup time zone

Tags: acumatica

I have a generic inquiry where the LastModifiedDateTime is one of the fieids - but it displays it in the format of what's in the database (GMT - 8 hrs) instead of converting it to the user's setup datetime (e.g., Pacific Standard)- which would show the wrong date if you're at or around midnight.  I know that there are screens that make this conversion internally - but I can't tell how.

Is there any way of making it display the proper (user's setup) datetime in a GI?

Comment: Can you give example of any screen that has such a feature?